# Nested Resources, ORM problems

Tags: loops, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, orm, nested

new to rails, and this one is kicking my butt.

I have an app that is set up to have Collections=>Lists=>links.

Collections

```
have_many :lists
belongs_to :user
```

Lists

```
have_many :links
belongs_to :collection
```

Links

```
belongs_to :list
```

Collections Controller

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @collection = Collection.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end

def new
    @collection = Collection.new
end

def show
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    # render :text => CGI.escapeHTML(@collection.inspect)
    redirect_to_good_slug(@collection) and return if bad_slug?(@collection)
end

def create
    @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)
    @collection.user_id = current_user.id
    # render :text => CGI.escapeHTML(@collection.inspect)
    if @collection.save
        redirect_to root_path(@user)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @collection.update(collection_params)
        redirect_to root_path(@user)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @collection.destroy
    # redirect_to root_path(@user)
end

private
  def collection_params
    params.require(:collection).permit(:alias, :notes, :visibility)
  end
  def find_collection
    @collection = @user.collection.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Lists Controller

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :find_collection, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update]

def new
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
end

def create
  @list = @collection.lists.build(list_params)
  @list.save!
  respond_to do |format|
        format.html {root_path(@collection.id)}
        format.js
    end
end

def edit
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {root_path(@collection.id)}
        format.js
    end
end

def update
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    if @list.update(list_params)
        redirect_to collection_path(@collection.id)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to collection_path(@collection.id)}
        format.js
    end
end

private
    def list_params
        params.require(:list).permit(:alias)
    end
    def find_collection
        @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
    end

end
```

Now, in the show view for collections I have a loop that does

```
<%= @collection.lists.each do |list| %>
```

Which is grabbing all the lists inside the collections, works great. I am trying to nest another loop here that grabs all the links for each list.

Links controller

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
before_filter :find_list, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update]

def new
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
end

def create
  @link = @collection.list.links.build(link_params)
  @link.save!
  respond_to do |format|
        format.html {root_path(@list.id)}
        format.js
    end
end

def edit
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {root_path(@list.id)}
        format.js
    end
end

def update
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    if @link.update(link_params)
        redirect_to list_path(@list.id)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to list_path(@list.id)}
        format.js
    end
end

private
    def link_params
        params.require(:link).permit(:url)
    end
    def find_list
        @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    end
end
```

I tried looping like this..

```
<%= @list.links.each do |link| %>
```

and

```
<%= @collection.lists.links.each do |link| %>
```

and

```
<%= @collection.list.links.each do |link| %>
```

and it throws no method for nil:class.

my routes look like..

```
devise_scope :user do
authenticated :user do
  root 'collections#index', as: :authenticated
   resources :collections do
    resources :lists
  end
      resources :lists do
      resources :links
  end
end
```

I think I am just bad at ORM, but I am new to the back-end all together and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate the `@collection.lists`, you are using block variable `list` which refers to a particular `list` instance. To grab all links for a list, you should be using the variable `list` as shown below:

```
<%= @collection.lists.each do |list| %>  <%# Notice block variable |list| %>
  <%= list.links.each do |link| %>
  ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Jesus that makes so much sense, I have been on a self inflicted crash course on rails and I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. :)  Please accept the answer when the timeout is over.